# Home Networking (wifi and wired)

Tags: networking

My home is hardwired but i have never used the setup, instead relying on Wifi setup. I am thinking of scaling the existing setup to allow for using the wired network too. A simple line diagram of current setup is:

ISP --> Cable Modem (2 ethernet ports) --> Use the existing hardwire to extend the internet to my Study --> Wifi Router (Linksys AC3200) --> all over the house.

I would like to keep the existing setup as it is and would like to expand my internet to all the hardwired port in my house. I was told that a switch will do but i could not make it work:

ISP --> Cable Modem --> Switch --> Wifi Router

Question : after cable modem what do i need to allow the internet connection to all the wired port in the house?

Thanks much 
Sam

Comment: What is the exact brand and model of your cable modem? True cable modems usually only have one Ethernet LAN port. Boxes with more than one LAN port are usually "cable gateways" (full home gateway routers that do NAT and DHCP service and maybe even have an integrated Wi-Fi AP, but also have an integrated DOCSIS cable modem). In most cases you need a NAT gateway between your modem and the rest of your network. So we need to know if your "modem" can be that NAT or not. If not, you'll need a router between the modem and the switch.

Comment: Easy, `ISP -> Cable modem -> [ AC3200 (WAN socket) <> AC3200 (LAN socket) ] -> Switch -> house wiring`. Done. All your kit can stay in your patch panel (where all your network cables start at the same place)/cupboard.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (which will be nice and tidy) is to keep everything in the same cupboard.

The only potential issue I see is the wifi if the cupboard is on one side of the house and the range might not reach the full length of the house/garden.

[image]